# threejs relation between mesh position and its binded geometry vertices position

Tags: three.js

I am looking for a way to manipulate a bundle of objects, usually one trick is to make groups, put objects as a group's children. But it is not working properly in my case.

What I want to do is binding a geometry and its wireframe together so I can manipulate them together. In the case of cube, I used a BoxGeometry and a BoxHelper. I created a mesh with BoxGeometry and created BoxHelper of the mesh. Then I want to translate/rotate/scale this bundle.

I did: geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(x, y, z) );
and I add this geometry to parent which worked fine.

But I notice the parent and mesh position is (0, 0, 0), and the BoxHelper position is (0, 0, 0) too. Why is the value not changing along with the geometry vertices? Is the position of an Object3D/Mesh/geometry a relative position to the its parent or in world space?

I tried to apply matrix to the parent. The result is, the mesh is in the right position but the frame is way off. Can anyone explain that? Thank you.

```
        var newcube = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 20, 20);
        // newcube.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(x, y, z); 
        var mats = [];
        mats.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffd500  }));
        mats.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x009e60  }));
        mats.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0051ba  }));
        mats.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff  }));
        mats.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: "yellow"  }));  // backward
        mats.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xC41E3A }));
        var faceMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(mats); 

        var parent = new THREE.Object3D();

        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(newcube, faceMaterial); 

        parent.add(mesh);

        var cubeframe = new THREE.BoxHelper( mesh );
        cubeframe.material.color.set( 0x0066ff );
        parent.add( cubeframe );

        parent.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(x, y, z); 

        scene.add(parent);
        objects.push(parent);
```

Comment: Helpers are designed to be added directly as children of the scene -- not as children of the target object, or any other object.

Comment: Thank you @WestLangley. So if I want to add/delete the object and its wireframe together, I should create the wireframe as a new mesh instead of using the boxhelper? Is there a better way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: I do not understand that question. If you need help, please make a new post and explain your issue in detail.